# ExtJS itemmouseenter(mouseover) grid row and change cell text to image

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs5

Hi I tried to change cell text to image when I itemmouseenter(mouseover) the grid row.

I have a event listener like this:

```
itemmouseenter: function(me, record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
    var store = this.getStore();
    var rowIndex = index;
    store.getAt(rowIndex).set('name', '<img src="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/icon-16.png" />');
}
```

Actually, it changed the text to image but It can't change back to original text.

My goal is just like css hover effect. Is any suggestions to do this trick?

Thanks

[Fiddle Sample](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/11sf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `record.set`, you will make the grid refresh which will affect performance. For this, I'd rather use CSS which will not cause a refresh.

Check out this fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/11st

Two things to look at:

1. No listeners on the grid
2. Check out the styles.css file to see the use of `:hover` and changing the `display` style

Using CSS instead of JavaScript like Gilsha's answer should lead to better performance.

Comment: Great! This way is much better

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. Updated [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/11sk)

```
listeners: {
    itemmouseenter: function(me, record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
        record.set('_name', record.get('name'));
        record.set('name', '<img src="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/icon-16.png" />');
    },
    itemmouseleave: function(me, record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
        record.set('name', record.get('_name'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Gilsha. It works well. I also add `markDirty:false` to my fiddle. This config will clear the small red triangle in the cell.

Comment: Instead of JavaScript and using `record.set`, use CSS for better performance.